# Highlighted TableView problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm working with a customized TableView and I have a problem when I click on a cell and it gets highlighted. After clicking on the cell, it gets highlighted and takes me to another view. The problem is that, when I return to the TableView screen, the cell is still highlighted.

Here is my code:

**In cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage 
imageNamed:@"CustomCell.png"]] autorelease];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CellHighlighted.jpg"]] autorelease];
```

**In didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
   Characteres *vCharacters = [[Characters alloc] initWithNibName:@"Characters" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    //vCharacters.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
    [self presentModalViewController:vCharactersr animated:YES];
    [vCharacters release];
    vCharacters = nil;*
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

This will deselect the row.